# End to end example of CQRS implementation on top of AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, architecture, cqrs

All of the infrastructure components required to implement a [CQRS](http://cqrsinfo.com/) based application seem to be out of the box within AppEngine.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything related to this subject.

Few possible reasons

- It's a well kept secret beyond "Architecture Astronauts"
- It's a worthless overkill architecture because AppEngine scales out "by design"
- It's not mainstream yet

However, even if no complete code is available, provided anyone has hints, bits of targeted code, pros/cons regarding CQRS on top of AppEngine, I'd be greatly honored to benefit from your knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

*Note 1: At least, a similar project exists in the .Net ecosystem (Lokad-CQRS which targets Windows Azure)

Note 2: Even if I'm rather python inclined, answers related to Java experience are welcome*

Comment: CQRS is not mainstream even on Java/.NET, so with AppEngine it's probably even more tough. That's a chance for you to be the first one to start a reference project :) CQRS is actually not that hard even with event sourcing (but highly addictive).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi there, this is not on AppEngine, however it is generic enough to help you get started:

- [Greg Young - Simplest Possible Thing](http://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r) The basic concepts
- [Mark  Nijhof - Fohjin](http://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin) Really good sample, I found this one easier to follow first

Also, I think this dude http://www.harukizaemon.com/ was trying some CQRS with Ruby, again not Python. But this could work as a guideline if you decide to go the Python way.

BTW, the [Google group DDD/CQRS](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dddcqrs) is really active and might be of help.

Cheers